# Stopping File system echoing/looping

Tags: c#, file, google-drive-api, synchronization, filesystemwatcher

I'm making an app that synchronises a remote and local file-tree, using the FileSystemWatcher class, for local changes, and Google's Drive Changes (List) API.

When a change is remotely made, the change is detected in the Changes list, and applied to the users local drive.

This then triggers the FileSystemWatcher class to push back (echo) the local change.

This would infinitely loop, if I didn't skip past the remote event that is raised when the local change is pushed.

I could do this:

```
Watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
DoWorkToFileTree();
Watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

But that doesn't seem like good code. Also, obviously, if a change is made while the work is being done, it will be missed.

I also worry that me skipping past the remote event opens up the possibility of me missing any remote events that occurred while the local event was being pushed.

If I let the echoed events raise, a loop will occur.
If I don't, I will miss changes that occur while events are being handled.

I've also thought about marking the events with some form of "IgnoreMe" attribute, but this seems dangerous; is this a good idea?

What's the best way to treat this?

I feel like I'm missing something, a standard technique for handling synchronisation like this.